# ASMX Json begins with ' [ ', not '{'

Tags: c#, asp.net, json, web-services, javascriptserializer

I'm creating a WebService Json Parser in C#/ASP.net using LINQ to SQL.

It works fine, but my JSON is returning in this way:

```
<string>[{"cli_id":1,"nome":"Joe"},{"cli_id":2,"nome":"Gary"},{"cli_id":3,"nome":"Ash"},{"cli_id":4,"nome":"Pedro"},{"cli_id":5,"nome":"Marcos"}]</string>
```

I am going to use this JSON with an android application, but many codes works fine when the json page start with ' { ', not with [.

How can I insert a { at the beginning?

I'm trying this code:

```
[WebService(Namespace = "http://tempuri.org/")]
[WebServiceBinding(ConformsTo = WsiProfiles.BasicProfile1_1)]
public class WebService : System.Web.Services.WebService {    
    public WebService () {}

    DataClassesDataContext dados = new DataClassesDataContext();

    [ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Json)]
    [WebMethod]
    public string getCustomers() {    
        var json = "";    
        var clientes = from result in dados.clientes select result;

        JavaScriptSerializer jss = new JavaScriptSerializer();    
        json = jss.Serialize(clientes);    
        return json;    
    }        
}
```

Comment: It's completly valid JSON: it's array of objects, How you want to represent it? With { at the begining, it won't be valid.

Answer (score 3):

> How can I insert a { at the beginning?

You don't want to. You want to consume it properly: As an *array* of objects.

You haven't shown your Android code for consuming it, but that code should be expecting the top level to be an array, not an object.

I mean, you *could* do this:

```
return "{\"clientes\": " + json + "}";
```

...so that your top level was an object with a single property, `clientes`, with the array of clients, but there's no reason to; what you're outputting is valid, it just needs to be consumed correctly.